# Sumar el resultado de columnas calculadas? PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

estoy intentando hacer una especie de tabla pivote con **Cases** y mi consulta es algo así:

```
Select coalesce((`user`), (`unauthuser`), ipstr(`srcip`)) as user_src, 
    Round( (case when app = 'MS-SQL' then sum(coalesce(`sentbyte`, 0)+coalesce(`rcvdbyte`, 0)) else 0 end) ,2) as SQL,
    Round( (case when app = 'Microsoft.Outlook.Office.365' then sum(coalesce(`sentbyte`, 0)+coalesce(`rcvdbyte`, 0)) else 0 end) ,2) as Outlook_365,
    Round( (case when app = 'HTTP' then sum(coalesce(`sentbyte`, 0)+coalesce(`rcvdbyte`, 0)) else 0 end) ,2) as HTTP,
    Round( (case when app = 'HTTPS.BROWSER' then sum(coalesce(`sentbyte`, 0)+coalesce(`rcvdbyte`, 0)) else 0 end) ,2) as HTTPS_BROWSER,
    Round( (case when app = 'QUIC' then sum(coalesce(`sentbyte`, 0)+coalesce(`rcvdbyte`, 0)) else 0 end) ,2) as QUIC,
    Round( (case when app = 'Microsoft.Portal' then sum(coalesce(`sentbyte`, 0)+coalesce(`rcvdbyte`, 0)) else 0 end) ,2) as Microsoft_Portal,
    Round( (case when app = 'tcp/50000' then sum(coalesce(`sentbyte`, 0)+coalesce(`rcvdbyte`, 0)) else 0 end) ,2) as tcp_50000,
    Round( (case when app = 'tcp/7100' then sum(coalesce(`sentbyte`, 0)+coalesce(`rcvdbyte`, 0)) else 0 end) ,2) as tcp_7100,
    Round( (case when app = 'MS.Windows.Update' then sum(coalesce(`sentbyte`, 0)+coalesce(`rcvdbyte`, 0)) else 0 end) ,2) as Windows_Update,
    Round( (case when app = 'Adobe.Web' then sum(coalesce(`sentbyte`, 0)+coalesce(`rcvdbyte`, 0)) else 0 end) ,2) as Adobe_Web,
    Round( (case when app = 'Google.Services' then sum(coalesce(`sentbyte`, 0)+coalesce(`rcvdbyte`, 0)) else 0 end) ,2) as Google_Services,
 sum(SQL+Outlook_365+HTTP,HTTPS_BROWSER+QUIC+Microsoft_portal+tcp_50000+tcp_7100+ Windows_Update+ Adobe_Web + Google_Services ) AS Total
    from $log where $filter and (logflag&1>0) and nullifna(app) is not null group by user_src,app /*order by Total*/
    limit 10
```

Mi problema, es la ultima suma de la consulta,donde intento sumar los resultados de las columnas calculadas, dice que no existe dicha columna.
He visto ejemplos sobre usar subconsultas o crear tablas, etc. El problema es que esta consulta se esta realizando en una herramienta llamada FortiAnalyzer de equipos Forti (redes) y no tiene la capacidad entera de alguna otra herramienta y no puedo utilizar cosas como el crosstab y cosas por el estilo.

Sin esa ultima suma si funciona pero necesito saber ese total para poder ordenarlo según la cantidad, si alguien sabe que podría hacer o si la nomenclatura es incorrecta o cualquier otra forma de poder hacerlo, lo agradecería.

Saludos

Comment: Qué versión de postgresql estás usando?

Answer (score 1):

Todo indica, de acuerdo a la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST), que sólo es posible referirse a los alias en las secciones de la consulta que hacen referencia al resultset ya filtrado: GROUP BY y ORDER BY.

> An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in
>   ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses, but not in the WHERE or HAVING clauses;
>   there you must write out the expression instead.

Esto significa que, para poder usar la función de agregación sobre alias de columnas, podrías usar una CTE o una subconsulta.

```
with cte1 as (
   select a, b, round(...) as GoogleWeb,...
   from ...
)
select
    a, b, sum(GoogleWeb,...) as Total
from cte1
```